# Flutter AnimatedSwitcher: make the switch out animation drive forward instead of reverse

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I have an animated switcher with a custom transition builder:

```dart
AnimatedSwitcher(
  transitionBuilder: (child, anim) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: anim,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: anim,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want both children to spin in the same direction, no matter if the child is being animated in or out. But at the moment one child spins one way and the other child the other way.

How can I make the switch in and switch out animations both drive forward? But only for the RotationTransition and not the FadeTransition.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem and found an answer for it.

You can achieve this by setting the reverseDuration to zero. Using your code as the base, it would be something like this:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
  transitionBuilder: (child, anim) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: anim,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: anim,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
)
```